# Centre div inside another

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble centering content of one div inside of another because the content doesn't appear.

```css
#searchbkg {
  postition: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #85e085;
}
#searchcentre {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbkg">
  <div id="searchcentre">Test</div>
</div>
```

The green box appears but there is no text inside of it.

Comment: Advice use Flex CSS3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: I see text inside of the green box, it just isn't centered.

Comment: `#searchcentre{ text-align:center; }`

Comment: This question has been asked a million times. Be sure to search for similar questions before posting your own. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

Comment: …and there is a documentation now, for this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/299/centering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is appearing fine, but it won't be centered because you have `position: absolute;` on the inside div. Change it to `position: relative;` and it will center horizontally. If you need the text to be centered within the div, you can also apply a `text-align: center;`.

```css
#searchbkg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #85e085;
}
#searchcentre {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbkg">
  <div id="searchcentre">This is a centered div!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make following 3 changes to make your content in center;

1. You have typo in one css property inside styles of `#searchbkg`. There is `postition` while it should be `position`.
2. Remove `position: absolute` from `#searchcentre` if not needed (Absolute positioning should be used only if you wants to place one element over another).
3. Add `text-align: center` in `#searchcentre`.

```css
#searchbkg{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #85e085;
}

#searchcentre{
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbkg">
  <div id="searchcentre">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
#searchbkg{
  postition: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #85e085;
  text-align:center;
}

#searchcentre{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbkg">
    <div id="searchcentre">Test</div>
  </div>
```